# My original data is weekly data, how do I plot it as weekly data in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

My data are originally in week (examples below). I find it difficult to perform time series data since this data is always in the from of `dd-mm-yy`.

```
    WEEK    SALES
  1: 29.2010  60.48
  2: 30.2010  95.76
  3: 31.2010  51.66
  4: 32.2010  73.71
  5: 33.2010  22.05
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ggplot(data, aes(x = WEEK, y = SALES, group = 1) + geom_line()

Comment: @ConorNeilson I tried this. It doesnt give the right plot.

Comment: @DoraFan I have updated my answer based on your new request. I also rolled back your edits because the new data frame you provided has different header as the old example, which may confuse the future reader. But I have figured out what the data you are working may look like.

Answer (score 0):

We can convert the week number as date using functions from the `lubridate` package, and then plot the date on the x-axis and `SALES` on the y-axis.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  separate(WEEK, into = c("WEEK", "YEAR"),  convert = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(Date = ymd("2010-01-01") + weeks(WEEK - 1))

ggplot(dat2, aes(x = Date, y = SALES)) +
  geom_line()
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "   WEEK    SALES
  1 '29.2010'  60.48
                  2 '30.2010'  95.76
                  3 '31.2010'  51.66
                  4 '32.2010'  73.71
                  5 '33.2010'  22.05",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
                  colClasses = c("character", "character", "numeric"))
```

**UPDATE**

If the data are from different years, we can use the following code.

```
dat2 <- dat %>%
  separate(WEEK, into = c("WEEK", "YEAR"),  convert = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(Date = ymd(paste(YEAR, "01", "01", sep = "-")) + weeks(WEEK - 1))
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "   WEEK    SALES
  1 '29.2010'  60.48
                  2 '30.2010'  95.76
                  3 '31.2010'  51.66
                  4 '32.2010'  73.71
                  5 '33.2010'  22.05
                  6 '1.2011'   37.5
                  7 '2.2011'   45.2
                  8 '3.2011'   62.9",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
                  colClasses = c("character", "character", "numeric"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works perfect for dates in 2010! However, I have data from 2011-2018 so when it comes to 2011, the data still stays in 2010, how can i fix that ? Thank you !

Comment: @DoraFan Please update your example data frame to reflect that data come from different years.

Comment: I updated it however I didn't manage to put the whole table there.

Comment: @DoraFan If my post solves your question, please consider to accept it as the answer.

Comment: @DoraFan If my post solves your question, please consider to accept it as the answer.